# Why does Typescript not validate input against a generic type default?

Tags: typescript-generics

Given the following function signature:

```js
const logIt = <T = string>(t: T) => {console.log(t)};
```

When I call the function without a generic parameter, I expect TS to validate the input according to the default generic type (here: string)

```js
logIt(1); // TS should raise a compilation error (number <> string)
logIt<string>(1) // This triggers an error (as expected)
logIt<number>(2) // This works fine (as expected)
```

I would like to know why the default generic type does not seem to do anything. I can replace it with anything and the input will not be validated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [release notes for TypeScript 2.3](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults), which added generic parameter defaults (emphasis mine):

> If a default type is specified **and inference cannot choose a candidate**, the default type is inferred.

In your code, the parameter `t: T` is a valid inference site for the type parameter `T`, so therefore `T` is inferred rather than falling back to the default. This is not great, because *most* of the time, a type parameter has at least one valid inference site; but for better or worse, it's how this is supposed to work.

As a workaround, you can use the `NoInfer` type (from [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829)) to prevent inference:

```
type NoInfer<T> = T extends infer S ? S : never

const logIt = <T = string>(t: NoInfer<T>) => {console.log(t)};
```

Demonstration:

```
logIt(1); // Error, as expected
logIt<string>(1) // Error, as expected
logIt<number>(2) // OK, as expected
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcg9gSQHYDMICcA8AVAfFAXimyggA9gIkATAZygEtUMoBlKAfjagC4okIANwwAoEQGM4SWsCgAbOAHMEsojkJQZ6JotwAKYH3jI0WPAEpC+AN6TpcORAB0CxQfMBfANxjXKvQCM5l5QAPShUACi6Ohw6AA0UACG9OSQ4pTUIn7AmFo6+kFhEdGxCcmpZOmZ2UoqmEgArgC2AEYY+gBMluFQAPIA0okppFUQGRBZQA)